# Multiple time series Analysis - References

Tags: time-series, references, econometrics

What is the most comprehensive book, containing a wide range of applications, for analyzing multiple time series (for cases where T is much larger than N) for economists?

Comment: Hi: lutkepohl's book is good for VAR analysis of multiple time series. I can't recall how many applications it has but it definitely has some. ttps://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-540-27752-1

Comment: William Wei also has a time series book for multivariate that doesn't restrict itself to VARS. I have it but it's in storage and I haven't gone through much of it. https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/book/10.1002/9781119502951